# How to split a line with \n in a list robotframework

Tags: robotframework

How to split a line with \n in a list robotframework

Example:
["abc\n    def\n    xyz\n]

Comment: You didn't post any robot code, and the python code that you posted isn't even valid python. Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates the actual problem in robot.

Comment: Example my list ["abc\n def\n xyz\n]  i want all to be different lines

Comment: You just repeated the list in the question, and it is not a valid python list and doesn't seem to have anything to do with robot framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use below snippet to split by \n in a string. Split String can be used to split based on delimiter. I hope this you're expecting.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    String

*** Test Cases ***
Test_Split
    ${Line} =     Set Variable    abc\n def\n xyz\n
    @{Splitted_Values} =    Split String    ${Line}    \n
    FOR    ${value}    IN    @{Splitted_Values}
        Log    {value}
    END
```